Axiom of Choice in Vitali construction
As I understand it the Axiom of Choice is needed to pick an element of each of an infinite collection of sets if it is not possible to choose them by giving some rule.
For example: For subsets of the natural numbers, a rule could be to always pick the smallest element.
So far, so good.
Now I read that in the construction of the Vitali set, the Axiom of Choice is needed.
However I think I can give a rule by which to pick elements so that it would not require the Axiom of Choice.
The part of the construction of the Vitali set I am referring to is the following:
Define equivalence classes as follows:
$$ A_x = \{ y \in (-1,1) \mid x - y \in \mathbb Q \}$$
Then pick one element from each of these $A_x$ to construct the Vitali set.
Now my question:
Why can't we use as a rule ''choose $x$ from $A_x$''?

You could do if the collection ${A_x}_{x}$ would have been finite. However, it's not the case, therefore you need axiom of choice

Why can't you? Because we know that it is consistent that the Axiom of Choice fails and there is no Vitali set.

You need the axiom of choice to be able to pick an element from infinitely many sets. That's precisely what the Axiom of Choice is.

That rule isn't well-defined because you would pick different representatives for $A_0$ and $A_\frac{1}{2}$ even though they are the same equivalence class.

Dear @NaïmFavier Thank you for your truly useful comment. What if we restrict $x$ to be $0$ in the single case where $x$ is rational? All the other cases we have that $x$ is an irrational from the set $(-1,1) $ and there is no choice because we need to create $A_x$ for all of them?

Of course there is choice.  Each $A_x$ is an infinite set.

You can still end up picking different elements from $A_{\sqrt2-1}$ and $A_{\sqrt2-2}$ (these two sets are equal).

Dear @ultralegend5385 Thank you for your very helpful reply. I now understand my mistake. I thought that there was only one $A_x$ for every irrational in $(-1,1)$. After reading your comment I see that this is wrong.

I have found it more useful to ask "why can I do this" or "why should this be true" (e.g. most examples of continuous functions we see early on are differentiable, so we may believe most are, but you would not really have a good reason for doing so and indeed it turns out to be opposite of the truth). In mathematics you have to be specifically "told" (via axioms) you can do things. Essentially, you can't just pick an element from each equivalence class because, in the absence of choice, there is no axiom (or theorem following from the axioms) that lets you do so.

This rule doesn't work because it is not well-defined. It will pick $x$ from $A_x$ and $y$ from $A_y$, and that is a problem if $x\neq y$ but $A_x=A_y$.
